# Accessing website with urllib returns error, retrieving information from Results Page

Tags: python, python-3.x, phone-number

I created a code in python so I could access a reverse phone lookup site and determine if a phone is a cell phone or land line. The website I am using is whitepages, whose results page will only include the phrase "VoIP" if the phone is a land line (which I have determined after looking at many results). However, I am getting an error at the website accessing stage. So far my code looks like:

```
import urllib

def Phone_Checker(number):
     url = 'http://www.whitepages.com/reverse_phone'
     enter = {'e.g. 206-867-5309': number}
     door= urllib.parse.urlencode(enter)
     open=door.encode('UTF-8')
     fight= urllib.request.urlopen(url, open)
     d = fight.read()
     v="VoIP"
     vv=v.encode("UTF-8")
     if vv in d:  #if VoIP  it is landline
          return False
     else:
          return True
```

I changed my strings into bytes because it was required for my variable "open" to be in bytes for urlopen. In a version of the code I made to access a different site it required a few other string conversion into bytes but I cannot quite remember which information required this conversion (just a heads up if the code after introducing the variable fight looks incorrect because I have not been able to debug the code which follows because of my difficulty with my urlopen. Whenever I run my code I receive this error

```
File "C:\Users\aa364\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 589, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: Requested Range Not Satisfiable
```

I was wondering how I could circumvent this error and if there is any possible alternative to creating a program to verify if a phone is mobile or a landline for DOMESTIC (USA) phone numbers. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can't asnwer your question but you may want to take a look at libphonenumber. There is a Python port on Github (https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have been trying to see if phonenumbers would be useful in this situation but I believe it can only help me with international phone numbers not in the domestic case which is what I am trying to do :/

Comment: Your approach is actually completely incorrect, there is a post need and a lot more going on, the url is also different, the final get is to `http://www.whitepages.com/phone/number` but the site limits the amount of calls from your ip so it is a dead end regardless

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stuff I'm reading and experimenting with to try to find an answer on this, I think this is likely whitepages' doing. I have 3 reasons:

1. the error seems to be a result of whitepages only accepting requests from certain browsers ('User-Agents')
2. Upon changing the 'User-Agent' I get kicked to robots.txt (which is basically a response meaning "don't automate this")
3. Both of these things are likely the result of whitepages having a paid/premium-access API: obviously, they'll do whatever they can to stop people from accessing their information for free if they're trying to charge for it

So, I think the answer in this case is, unfortunately, find another phonenumber lookup.